# Draw the frame on the button edge

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, drawing

I have some buttons. I need to mark some of them. I would like to make it by frames.
Can I realize it? Can I draw the frame on the buttons edge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add QuartzCore framework to your project. Modify buttons as follows:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

.........

button.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;
button.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
button.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0; //optional, if you need rounded corners
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to give size of frame slightly larger than that of button else the button may overlap the frame and wont be visible.